# Heroku Database

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-toolbelt

Good day,
I have a Django app that I hosted on Heroku with the codes from GitHub, it deployed fine and I have a domain, for instance `myapp.herokuapp.com`.
But when I make some changes to the website itself, everything seems alright, then I make changes in the code and push it to GitHub. It deploys again perfectly, but all the former changes I made on the website get discarded, it now looks like a fresh deployed app.
Auto-deploy from GitHub is enabled in my Heroku settings.

how can I retain changes I make on the Heroku website after updating my code??

Comment: I suppose you are using SQLite https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku Dynos have an [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) file system therefore it cannot be used to persist data (at every redeployment all local changes are discarded).

You can use a database, either external ([MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas1)) or the [Heroku Postgres](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql), both have a free tier.

If you need to save simple files you can use an external storage service (S3, Dropbox, even GitHub). See [Files on Heroku](https://medium.com/geekculture/files-on-heroku-cd09509ed285) for details and examples.